# discord.py запуск бота с двумя токенами

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Использую библиотеку discord.py

Во время работы скрипта мне нужно сменить токен(перезапустить бота с другим токеном), при этом не выходя из скрипта. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: [logout()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.logout)

Answer (score 3):

Это возможно. Для этого понадобится 2 файла: файл 1 бота и файл 2 бота. В 1-м файле создаём переменную, которая будет содержать новый токен(например переменная new_token), добавить новый токен можно при помощи функции input(). После этого прописываем код для открытия файла №2, импортируя туда нашу переменную new_token.

Comment: Да, ты прав, можно добавить функцию на обновление токена через .txt или ввод консоли.

Comment: Прими мою благодарность)